# Getting Build Error Creating Android Application using Xamarin Extension for Visual Studio 2015 Preview

Tags: android, c#-6.0, visual-studio-2015

I'm using recently released Visual Studio 2015 Preview along with Xamarian Studio 5.6.3(or 5.6.2) extension for Visual studio.

After Hours of downloading and installing all required software (all done successfully), I started developing Android Application in VS2015P, but every time I create blank Android application, I get this error, with no error code:

> The "MergeApkRecipelists" task was not given a value for the required parameter "RecipeFiles".

Comment: We have a bug logged for this here: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=24510

Comment: I'm seeing this for VS2010 & VS2013. I can't get VS2015 to even see that Xamarin is installed. Seems like bugs abound. You'd know Xamarin was involved.

Comment: @DaveDev try going to Programs and Features and modifying the Xamarin installation.  Could be that VS 2015 integration needs to be enabled - that was the case for me.

Answer (score 4):

Figured this out by looking at Xamarin's .targets files.

**Short Version**

You can either:

- Create an Android C++ library project and reference that from your Xamarin Android project

*or*

- Comment out the `Import` element defined in %PROGRAMFILES(x86)%\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.After.targets.  Note this will likely disable support for adding C++ project references to Xamarin Android projects.

Once you do one of those, your Xamarin Android project should build and run.

**Long Version**

First, note the error in the VS output window:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common\ImportAfter\Microsoft.Cpp.Android.targets(54,9): error MSB4044: The "MergeApkRecipelists" task was not given a value for the required parameter "RecipeFiles".`

The Microsoft.Cpp.Android.targets file mentioned in the error looks to be all about supporting project references to C++ projects.  In it, the element for the `MergeApkRecipelists` task looks like so:

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->
<MergeApkRecipelists RecipeFiles="@(_NativeAndroidRecipeFiles)">
        ...
</MergeApkRecipelists>
```

The `NativeAndroidRecipeFiles` variable doesn't seem to be defined in the .targets files, so presumably it's being initialized by the build process.  But since the .targets file seems to be aimed at supporting C++ project refs, I tried adding an Android C++ shared library project to my solution:

[image: Adding Dynamic Shared Library (Android) project]

Then I referenced the C++ project from my Xamarin Android project, and voila!  Building and running afterwards was successful.

But since it's pretty onerous to have to bring in a dummy lib, I also tracked down where Xamarin's Microsoft.Cpp.Android.targets file gets pulled in.  This happens in the C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.After.targets file, which has one `Import` element:

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->
<Import Project="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)\Xamarin.Android.Common\ImportAfter\*"
        Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)\Xamarin.Android.Common\ImportAfter')"/>
```

That brings in everything under %PROGRAMFILES(x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common\ImportAfter.  Since the only item in that directory is the .targets file we want to exclude, this can be commented out without affecting anything else.  But **note** that, since this .targets file appears to be part of support for referencing C++ projects from Xamarin Android projects, commenting this out presumably means that will no longer work properly.

With that `Import` statement commented out, the Xamarin Android project should build and run without any C++ references.

Comment: Thanks Rich just got this error minutes before your response and it worked like a charm.  Don't forget to file a bug report with Xamarin.

Comment: @J Chapman - I can't file a bug directly, so I've [posted the info to the Xamarin forums](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/27820/xamarin-3-9-android-visual-studio-build-error-and-workaround)

Comment: You can also apply the proper fix in the meantime (which we've implemented in the product and should go out really soon). Just add  the following condition on line 54 of the targets file at C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common\ImportAfter\Microsoft.Cpp.Android.targets:  `<MergeApkRecipelists RecipeFiles="@(_NativeAndroidRecipeFiles)" Condition="'@(_NativeAndroidRecipeFiles)' != ''">`

Answer (score 1):

Just add the following condition on line 54 of the targets file at C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common\ImportAfter\Microsoft.Cpp.A‌​ndroid.targets:

`<MergeApkRecipelists RecipeFiles="@(_NativeAndroidRecipeFiles)" Condition="'@(_NativeAndroidRecipeFiles)' != ''">`

Note: this permanent fix will ship soon in the alpha channel.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update Xamarin up to 3.9.
[Update](http://developer.xamarin.com/releases/vs/xamarin.vs_3/xamarin.vs_3.9/)

Answer (score 0):

Update Xamarin from http://developer.xamarin.com/releases/vs/xamarin.vs_3/xamarin.vs_3.9/ 
I did it and it works.